# Access viewModel in javascript function outside viewModel's scope

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, scope

I'm wondering if I can access the knockout.js main viewModel from a method outside the scope of the viewModel itself. Take this example:

```
function Employee(data) {
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
}

function EmployeeViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.employees = ko.observableArray([]);

  this.loadEmployees = function() {
    var mappedEmployees= $.map(JSON.parse(data.value), function(item) { return new Employee(item) });
    self.employees (mappedEmployees);
  }
}

// here's the part I'm curious about
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeViewModel());  

  $("#myLink").click(function() {
     // is there some way to get back into the ko context here?
     // like with ko.dataFor or ko.contextFor?
  });
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can always access it just by storing your viewmodel in a variable you can access, the [module and revealing module patterns](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-module-pattern) are nice, but you can just store it in an object that won't conflict with other names ('my' here):

```
my = { viewModel: new EmployeeViewModel() };
ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel);
```

You had the right idea, you just need to take the element as an argument to your click function and pass the target property to ko.dataFor or ko.contextFor ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEG3k/65/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    my.vm = new EmployeeViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
    $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        alert('you clicked on employee ' + ko.contextFor(e.target).$data.name() +
             ' also known as ' + ko.dataFor(e.target).name());
    });
});​
```

Instead of using jQuery to bind the click event, you can always use [the Knockout click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html), which passes the current model data as the first parameter and the event as the second parameter ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VUtAd/14/)):

```
function EmployeeViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  // skipped some of your code

  this.clickedOnEmployee = function(model, event) {
    // assuming your Employee has a name observable
    alert('You clicked on employee ' + model.name());
  };
}
```

In your html (the $root is your base view model, you wouldn't need it if your clickedOnEmployee function was on your Employee objects):

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: employees">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        <button data-bind="click: $root.clickedOnEmployee">show</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this (correct) answer, but I'm wondering if there is still a way to access the info out of the context just for future reference?

Comment: added those details up front, ko.dataFor and ko.contextFor just need the dom node, which you can get looking at the event in your handler function.  $root on the result of contextFor would be your view model