# Knockout-arrays as global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I probably show off my lack of skills with this one. But since I´m all for learning I´m willing to let pride go...

In my viewModel I define:

```
self.Tags() = ko.observableArray();
self.Skills() = ko.observableArray();
```

then I want to save my tags. I have created this function outside the viewModel where I do some processing:

```
function saveTags( category, mytagsArray) { ... }
```

I call 'saveTags( "skill", Skills)' from within the viewModel and get this error telling me self.Tags() is not a function.

Why am I not allow to refer self.Tags inside the function "saveTags"?

(And please do not say it should be LackOfSkills instead of Skills... ;)

Comment: check my demo or the sample code I have pasted. It uses the object literal way of defining your viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a demo pen for you](http://cdpn.io/dqbhz). Try defining your view model like this:

```
var tagsViewModel = {
    // data
    tagToAdd: ko.observable(""), // this is the new tag to add
    tags: ko.observableArray([]), //empty collection
    skills: ko.observableArray([]),

// behaviors
    addTag: function () {
        var newTag = { Name: this.tagToAdd() };
        this.tagToAdd("");

        tagsViewModel.tags.push(newTag)

    }
};

ko.applyBindings(tagsViewModel);
```

Define your html like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Tag" data-bind="value: tagToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /> <button data-bind="click: addTag, enable: tagToAdd().length > 0" class="btn"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</button>

 <ul data-bind="foreach: tags" class="">
<!-- DEFINE UR LI HERE -->
</ul>
```

Comment: @AsleG check my demo or the sample code I have pasted. It uses the object literal way of defining your viewmodel.

Comment: @AsleG As you can see in the addtag function, I am using tags, tagtoadd properties, in the same way you can use from your SaveTags function. Only the name is different but it is doing the same thing I guess i.e. adding item to array.

Comment: @AsleG if my sample demo or the above code solves your problem or informs you to how to write your vm in a right way, kindly accept my soln as answer :P

Answer (score 2):

try without the ()'s:

```
self.Tags = ko.observableArray();
self.Skills = ko.observableArray();
```

`self.Tags = foo` says to set the self.Tags to be foo.  `self.Tags()` says that self.Tags in a function and you want to invoke it.  Those are both legit statements.  But `self.Tags() = foo` says self.Tags is a function you want to invoke and set it's value to foo... which doesn't make sense and isn't valid code in any language.

Answer (score 1):

You can access your viewmodel by storing it in a variable like so:

```
function ViewModel() {
     self.Tags = ko.observableArray();
     self.Skills = ko.observableArray();
}
my = { viewModel: new ViewModel() };
ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel);
```

Then you just access `my.Tags()`

[related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10644169/168097)

Comment: i just copy pasted his code without checkin. thank you it's fixed now

Comment: Thanks @Circadian! This is pretty close to my model. Inside the function ViewModel() {} I have a method self.saveAll = function(){...}
It is from within this I wanted to call "saveTags()" as an external function. (I can get it to work if I include "self.SaveTags()" as an ViewModel-internal method as well. So would I be able to do that with refering to my.Tasks() etc?

Comment: i guess so yes. try it out

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you assigning `ko.observableArray();` to result of the call `self.Tags()`, and that is why your function is not stored in `self.Tags` variable. I guess the right code will look like:
in case you want assign the results of that calls:

```
self.Tags = ko.observableArray();
self.Skills = ko.observableArray();
```

in case you want assign the function links to call them later:

```
self.Tags = ko.observableArray;
self.Skills = ko.observableArray;
...
// somewhere later
self.Tags();
```