# Knockoutjs how to access view model from outside function

Tags: knockout.js

I found some similar examples to what I'm trying to do in [Access viewModel in javascript function outside viewModel's scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643940/knockout-js-access-viewmodel-in-javascript-function-outside-viewmodels-scope), but have not been able to figure out what to do in my particular case. I have several teachers, show their salaries, along with total salaries, but want to show the relative percentage of their salary as it relates to the total. Here's my view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    <th>Salary Percent</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: teachers">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: salary"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: salaryPercent"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Total Salary</td>
    <td data-bind="text: totalSalary"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

view model:

```
var Teacher = function(id, name, salary) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.salaryPercent = ko.computed(function() {
        // return accounting.toFixed((this.salary/178000)*100, 0) + '%';    // works with hard-coded total salary
        return accounting.toFixed((this.salary/viewModel.totalSalary)*100, 0) + '%';
        // return this.salary;    // works, returns the same salary as this.salary above
    }, this);
};

var viewModel = function(teachers) {
    var self = this;
    self.teachers = ko.observableArray(teachers);
    self.totalSalary = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.teachers(), function(teacher) { total += teacher.salary; });
        return total;
    });
};

var initialTeachers = [
    new Teacher(1, "Tom", 40000),
    new Teacher(2, "Betty", 41000),
    new Teacher(3, "Charles", 45000),
    new Teacher(4, "Daniel", 52000)
];

var vm = new viewModel(initialTeachers);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

and css:

```
td, th {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/2tgqb4gg/15/)

TIA, Steve

Note: I'm using the accounting.js library, included with jsfiddle.

Comment: The problem is in the line `return accounting.toFixed((this.salary/viewModel.totalSalary)*100, 0) + '%';`. `viewModel` is not defined within the current scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2tgqb4gg/24/) does what you were looking to do in the first place. I added a function inside `viewModel`, `calculateSalaryPercent`, which takes a salary as an argument. I removed `salaryPercent` from `Teacher` since it's now calculated at a higher level.

One quick note: calling `accounting.toFixed` with zero decimal places can result in percentages that add up to less than 100%.

Comment: Sweet - this is what I was looking for. I'm still learning knockout, and had started to put a function in the view model, but couldn't figure out how to call it. It's clear I need to read about $parent and $root!

Comment: Good! Props to you for taking the time to put it together in JSFiddle.

Comment: On the percentages not adding up to 100%, yeah, that's somewhat of an issue, but even the requirements document I've got shows whole numbers that add up to 99%. Interestingly, changing to a precision of 1 allows it to add up to 100%, but precision of 2 displays 99.99%. For this particular application, it's really more of a rough estimate and we're replacing a spreadsheet that was already doing the same thing in showing whole numbers. Not an issue for them, but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Besides gorilly's solution, the other way is to build the logic directly on the view itself using knockout's binding context `$parent`.

But this solution is ugly for people (not me) who pursue "logic-less template".

http://jsfiddle.net/2tgqb4gg/27/

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: teachers">
 <tr>
  <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
  <td data-bind="text: salary"></td>
  <td data-bind="text: accounting.toFixed(salary/$parent.totalSalary()*100,0)+'%'"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: For the record, this works, and appreciate very much the additional education here. I just don't/haven't had my brain wrapped around how $parent and $root works yet. Thanks for this.